# average of elements within a window of size NbyN of an array

Tags: python, moving-average

The objective is to get the average of elements within the window/kernal.

Example case :

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,np.nan]])
window size - 2 by 2
ex: overlying window on x  sum(x[0,0]+x[0,1]+x[1,0]+x[1,1])/4 = 1.5
>> y
array([[ 1.5  ,  3.5  ],
       [ 1.5  ,  3.333]])
```

**Tried approach :  (I) via loop which is hardcoded for a window of size 2,2**

```
S,T = x.shape
viArray_at_LR = np.empty([S/2,T/2])
viArray_at_LR[:] = np.nan
rowIncre = 0
for s in range(0,S-1,2):
    colIncre = 0
    for t in range(0,T-1,2):
        try:
            viArray_at_LR[rowIncre,colIncre] = np.nanmean([x[s,t],x[s,t+1],x[s+1,t],x[s+1,t+1]])
        except KeyError:
            print "nan values at ",s,t
        colIncre = colIncre + 1
    rowIncre = rowIncre + 1
```

**II) using kernals, this returns the same size of the array as the kernal jump is by an element.**

```
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
out = ndimage.generic_filter(array, np.nanmean, footprint=kernel, mode='wrap')
```

I want the ouput array.size to be  input_arr.size/window.size

I am looking for a general approach where this can done for any window size (N,N) without the use of loops

Comment: do you want the same size array or to shrink it by a factor of window_size^2 ?

Comment: @mmdanziger, I want to shrink it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you use CUDA or something you are going to be using loops.  Also, any window size is perhaps not such a good idea because it has undefined behavior for the edges.  If you use a window size which is a divisor of the array size `N` you can do the following:

```
def coarsegrain(x,w=2):
    N = len(x)
    M = N//w
    y = zeros((M,M))
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(M):
            y[i,j] = np.nanmean(x[w*i:w*i+w,w*j:w*j+w])
    return y
```

And if you want to wrap the indices around you can use "fancy" indexing like this:

```
def coarsegrain_wrap(x,w=2):
    N = len(x)
    M = int(ceil(N/w))
    y = zeros((M,M))
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(M):
            y[i,j] = np.nanmean(numpy.take(x,[list(range(w*i,(w*i+w))),list(range(w*j,(w*j+w)))],mode="wrap"))
    return y
```

Generally speaking, I would highly recommend sticking with window sizes that are integer divisors of the array size.  Anything else will generate boundary artifacts.  However, if the array is large enough, the artifacts are not such a big deal and can probably be trimmed off.  Wrapping `range` in `list` is only necessary in Python3.

Comment: Thanks!!! This works for me. I was not sure if kernels could achieve the goal, so i posted on SO.